# How to differentiate with respect to input variables in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to see how sensitive my tensorflow model is to perturbations in the input. Is there a way to differentiate my cost function with respect to the placeholder input variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) function.

Comment: Thanks! That was easy enough.